# jQuery, Ajax problem?

Tags: jquery

I have one table, and when I click on row, it loads some content in another table.

The problem is, when I click on row the first time it loads just one time (message 'Some msg' and message 'Some other msg' is shown one time). When I click on another row, it loads twice (messages is shown twice). The third time when I click on row it loads three times, etc.

Here is my code:

```
$("#myTable tr").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $full_path_ajax_php; ?>',
        data:{'what':'2','mypath':'12345678'},
        dataType:'json',
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend:function(){alert('Some msg')},
        success: function(){alert('Some other msg')}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `.live()` function in the parent table but don't use this code in the portion which you are going to use:

```
$("#myTable tr").live('click', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $full_path_ajax_php; ?>',
        data:{'what':'2','mypath':'12345678'},
        dataType:'json',
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend:function(){alert('Some msg')},
        success: function(){alert('Some other msg')}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Remember, only once in the parent page or table.

Comment: Tnx man,that work fine,I'll look live event to understand it better my problem.Tnx.

Comment: I think that I dont have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use id instead of 'tr', and you will get the id in function's click event. I think this may work, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I do not understand what are you suggesting, can you give an example?
But still think that isnt solution.Tnx

Comment: I try to use 'id' instead of 'tr',still dont work,can someone help me with this,it is annoying,...

Comment: hey do you have child tables within #myTable ??

Comment: No,I dont have.Starx solve my problem,thank you for your time Chirag